# Custom tabLayout badge view getting cut off [Android]

Tags: android, view, android-tablayout

For the tab layout, am inflating custom layout *custom_tab.xml*, Where the badge view is getting cut off if the length of the name is increased.

I have tried **wrap_content** for all views, still no effect

This is the *custom_tab.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="48dp"
              android:layout_margin="5dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/tv_count"
        android:layout_width="31dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_drawable"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the java code for inflating views for tablayout

```
private void setupTabIcons() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NewFragment.categories.size(); i++) {
        try {
            LinearLayout currentTabLayout = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);

            ..............................
            ..............................

            tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(currentTabLayout);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Screen shot for text having increased length with single line set as false

[image]

Screen shot for text having increased length with single line set as true

[image]

which in both case cuts the badge view from the layout
I want the text view to be single line.

Can anyone please help me fixing this issue.

Any kind of help or suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Sanoop you can try to use "marquee" property for set to one line because your text is long

Comment: @DileepPatel Thanks for the reply, I have tried but it had little effect on the badge view, it is still hidden from the view

Comment: I guess it's not possible if the text is too long to fit in, tab layout will try to fit 3 tabs if the mode is set 'fixed',i had to shrink the text for the same requirement

Comment: Well currently am having 7 tabs. and its scrollable. Not having issues with other tab headings. Just this one if i set text length to higher. @hardikm

Comment: okay, will try to make this ui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by setting width to a higher level under **dimens.xml** file under tag

```
<dimen name="tab_max_width">XXXdp</dimen>
```